# How to wrap text in balloon in Perl/Tk

Tags: perl, user-interface, perltk

How can I wrap the text displayed in a balloon in Perl/Tk?

my code is something like this

```
my $balloon1 = $mw->Balloon();
my $txt = "file Name: ".$fileName."\n"."location: ".$path;
$balloon1->attach($button, -balloonmsg=>$txt);
```

But this help text in balloon goes out of screen boundaries. Is there a way to wrap the text displayed in a balloon?

Comment: This may help you. [Text Widgets](http://perlguru.com/gforum.cgi?post=58879;search_string=balloon;guest=#58879)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Label widget inside the Balloon is advertised as the "message" subwidget and may be accessed directly using:

```
my $balloon1_label = $balloon1->Subwidget('message');
```

You can apply all `Tk::Label` configure options here, for example the `-wraplength` option:

```
$balloon1_label->configure(-wraplength => 100);
```